# Knowing how many repeat the letters in the String

Tags: java

i have an interview Question which is 
Knowing repeat the letters in the String 
i solve it like this

```
String str = "my name is Java Developer";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                count = count + 1;
            }

        }
        System.out.print(count + "  ");
        count = 0;
    }
```

but 
my problem was 
1 - avoid the space from count
2-there is repeated character counted like m in 'my' and m in 'name'
i don't want to repeat the count for the characters
3- i want to solve it in another way plus this one

thank you ,,

Comment: Please show expected output vs. actual output. You can visit the [ask] page to [edit] your question so we can best help you.

Comment: Only count letters, so not spaces, digits, and other characters? How about uppercase vs. lowercase? Are they considered equal?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use maps (from Character to Integer)?

Hence you won't need double for-loops and it solves your double counting.

But since it is an interview question I hesitate to give you the code.

Answer (score 0):

1- You could use a token delimiter to remove the spaces before counting the characters in the string
2- you could have n integer array A of size 26, where the index 0 -25 each represent corresponding alphabets i.e 0-A 1-B. Every time a letter is encountered then the A[char value of letter - 'A'] is incremented to 1. Then the counter is only incremented if the value at A[letter] is 0.

Comment: You mean an integer array of size 26 with index 0-25 :-)?

Comment: Yeah :|. I'll edit it. thanks

Comment: This can be achieved by continuously storing the letters in a array list of character and storing the count for that particular letter in hash map with character as the key.